# Postgresql Batch insert and on conflict batch update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to batch insert rows into a postgres db and on conflict update the conflicted rows. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. The query I'm currently fails to insert any rows, but if I remove the on conflict, it works perfectly. I'm also not getting any errors from what I can tell.

Here is the current query I'm using:

`'INSERT INTO table (x1, x2, x3, ...) VALUES %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET (x4, x5, x6) = %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,...'`

I have a function which populates the %s values with tuples of the form (x1, x2, ...)

My table looks like this

`Table "public.table"
    Column    |  Type   |                           Modifiers

--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------
 id           | integer | not null default nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass)
 x1           | text    | not null
 x2           | text    | not null
 x3           | integer | not null
 x4           | text    | not null
 x5           | text    | not null
 x6           | text    | not null
Indexes:
    "table_feature_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)`

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: Not quite understanding what this has to do with batch-files? Not seeing any batch-file code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to use obviously incorrect syntax. Having the table

```
create table a_table(id serial primary key, x1 int, x2 int);
```

try this in **psql**

```
insert into a_table (x1, x2) 
values (1,2), (3,4)
on conflict do
update set (x1, x2) = (1,2), (3,4);
```

to get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "3"
LINE 4:  update set (x1, x2) = (1,2), (3,4);
```

On the other hand, `ON CONFLICT` makes no sense in this case. A conflict will never happen, as none of the used columns (or group of columns) is unique.

Check [`INSERT` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html), read more about [`UPSERT` in wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29).

Comment: so what if say columns x1 and x2 together were unique? Do I have to specify that somehow when I create the table and then do something like 'on conflict (x1, x2) do update'?

Comment: Practically when inserting multiple rows (assuming that columns or group of columns are unique) the reasonable way is to `on conflict ... do nothing`, because `update` cannot affect the same row many times (as with many inserts this may happen).

Answer (score 4):

1.before insert

[image]

2.command

[image]

3.after insert

[image]

Comment: EXCLUDED is the keyword here.